# How do I access a child component's input value inside a parent component in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a date component with the following:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="idName" class="col-xs-2 dateParagraphs" >{{transition }} Date: </label>
      <datepicker v-model="dateObject" class="col-xs-2 dateParagraphs" id="datepickerID"></datepicker>
      <label class="col-xs-3" >{{transition }} Time: </label>
      <vue2-timepicker class="col-xs-3 dateParagraphs" format="hh:mm:ss a" id="timepick" ></vue2-timepicker>
   </div>
</div>
</template>
```

The datepicker and vue2-timepicker are the two child components. In my App.vue file, I access them twice:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="dates">
        <date transition="Beginning"  class="dateAndTime"></date>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <date transition="Ending"  class="dateAndTime"></date>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want to get the input value of each of the timepicker and datepicker. Since each of the values for the timepicker and the datepicker will be different, how would I go about getting the two input values for each of the timepicker and the datepicker?

Comment: Use `v-model`, `$emit` or `sync`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events

Comment: Can I get a specific example?

Comment: Why don't you take a stab at it after reading the documentation I linked, and if you need help along the way I (or someone else) can answer specifics.

Comment: Got it working. Thanks!